# how to query_posts by category slug

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code to list some pages on my wordpress site:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'tcp_product', 'paged' => $paged);
?>
  <?php query_posts($args); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="prod-link">
  <?php if( has_sub_field('images') ): ?>
  <?php $img = get_sub_field('image') ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['product-index-pic'] ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  </a>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- #posts -->
  <div class="pagination">
    <?php posts_nav_link( ' ', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/assets/images/prev.jpg" />', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/assets/images/next.jpg" />' ); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- .pagination -->
```

I am wondering if there would be a way to limit those based on a certain category slug? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

tax_query is used to get the posts associated with certain taxonomy.

- **{tax}** (*string*) - use taxonomy slug. **Deprecated** as of Version 3.1 in favor of 'tax_query'.
- **tax_query** (*array*) - use taxonomy parameters (available with Version 3.1).

  - **taxonomy** (*string*) - Taxonomy.
  - **field** (*string*) -  Select taxonomy term by ('id' or 'slug')
  - **terms** (*int/string/array*) - Taxonomy term(s).
  - **include_children** (*boolean*) -  Whether or not to include children for hierarchical taxonomies. Defaults to true.
  - **operator** (*string*) - Operator to test. Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tcp_product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tcp_product_taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'your-cat-slug'
        )
     )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post;
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes it that it returns no posts. what would I be doing wrong?

Comment: I put the code as I used it in jsfiddle since it doesn't work to do it in a comment. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=g3ztCx7NB9

Comment: replace tcp_product_taxonomy with your taxonomy slug

Comment: Ok. I'm a little new to taxonomies. would that be "category"?

Comment: If you have used woocommerce then please check the below image, highlighted link is custom taxonomy
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bd1x3nq88

A Basic Explanation of WordPress Taxonomies
http://www.vsellis.com/a-basic-explanation-of-wordpress-taxonomies/

Comment: Thanks! I am using thecartpress and I had to figure out the taxonomy which was tcp_product_category. As soon as I used that it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

You can use the variable `category_name` like this:

```
$args = array( 'category_name' => ***YOUR CATEGORY SLUG***, 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'tcp_product', 'paged' => $paged);
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some more explanation about this variable and/or links to documentation files

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Anyone looking for documentation you can find it here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/